# Certificate error on Azure web app with redirect from www to non-www https

Tags: azure, ssl, redirect, web-config

I want to redirect any `www` subdomain requests to `domain.co.uk`, for example

```
http://www.domain.co.uk
https://www.domain.co.uk
```

should redirect to

```
https://domain.co.uk
```

I have an SSL cert in Azure bound to `domain.co.uk`

In the Azure portal, in Custom Domains I have set to `HTTPS only`

In web.config I have the following redirect rule

```
<rule name="NonWwwRedirect"  stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    <conditions> 
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domain\.co.uk$" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.co.uk/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```

> Requests to `https://www.domain.co.uk` give an error saying your connection is not private

Does anyone know why?

Requests to `http://www.domain.co.uk` redirect to `http://domain.co.uk` as expected

Comment: Because your certificate is created for `domain.co.uk` and you are accessing `www.domain.co.uk`.

Comment: But it should redirect to `domain.co.uk` ?

Comment: The connection does not make it past the handshake so it never gets the redirect.